# g++ python errors

Tags: macos

I'm trying to compile some basic c++ programs for school but g++ keeps throwing errors about python files.

I type:

```
g++ -Wall mult3-5.cpp -o mult3-5
```

The command returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/grc", line 161, in <module> os.execvp(args[0], args)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what was wrong? I'm getting the same problem with grc.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Please let us know if you were ever able to fix it.